# Removes the fully bound object in hibernate, tell the correct type of cascade

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Can anyone tell me what type of cascade to ask?

**In 1 entity field is:**

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "client", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Ticket> tickets = new ArrayList<>();
```

**In 2 this:**

```
 @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "client_id")
    private Client client;
```

It is necessary that when deleting 2 enenties (where manytoone) only it is deleted, and the object associated with it deleted only the link. Already everything was repetitive

Comment: I don't understand your question. Make an example what you want to delete